# Audio loading with XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, web-audio-api

I am learing Web Audio API. Im having a problem in loading my sound file thourgh XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript. Kindly please help.Here is my code

```
var source;

function start() {
  console.log("WELCOME!!");
  try{
    var actx = new AudioContext();
  }catch(e){
    console.log('WebAudio api is not supported!!');
  }

  source = actx.createBufferSource()

  var req  = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET','src3.ogg',true);
  req.responseType='ArrayBuffer';

  req.onload = function(){
    var audioData = req.response;
    actx.decodeAudioData(audioData,function(buffer){
      source.buffer = buffer;
      source.connect(actx.destination);
      source.loop();
    },
    function(e){
      console.log('Error in decoding audio'+e.err);
    }

  );
  }
  req.send();
}

function play() {
  source.start(0);
}
function stop(){
  source.stop(0);
}
```

Browser is showing this error this:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///home/uzumaki/Web_Audio_Projects/src3.ogg
Line Number 1, Column 5:
```

And *start()* method is called on the **onload** event of body  tag

Comment: Are you trying the code at Chromium or Chrome?

Comment: its in FireFox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute

```
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

for

```
req.responseType = "ArrayBuffer";
```

[`.responseType`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responsetype-attribute) is not converted to lowercase by `XMLHttpResponse` instance